# Visual Basic: Image moves up and and then back down after a button click

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio, animation

I am attempting to make a character appear to jump straight up in the air and then come back down and return to the same level he started at. (y=100) The code below seems to make the program fight itself and move him up and down at the same time.

I have tried countless methods and all of them resulted in the guy either going up and not coming back down or flying off the page.

```
Private Sub btnJump_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnJump.Click  
    tmrJump.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub tmrJump_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrJump.Tick
    For intCounterUp As Integer = 100 To 15
        picSpaceRunner.Location = New Point(intCounterX, intCounterY)
        intCounterY = intCounterUp
    Next intCounterUp
    For intCounterDown As Integer = 15 To 100
        picSpaceRunner.Location = New Point(intCounterX, intCounterY)
        intCounterY = intCounterDown
    Next intCounterDown
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is VB.NET, not C++

Answer (score 0):

The code is running with no delay, so you're at the mercy of the machine.

I'm not a professional game coder, so I couldn't explain the intricacies of modern game engines. However, one of the basic ideas I learned a long time ago is to control your game/animation loop. Consider the frames per second.

In your code, it could be as simple as adding a delay within each loop iteration. If you want the character to complete his jump in 2 seconds (1 second up, 1 second down), then divide 1000 (1 sec = 1000 ms) by the number of iterations in each loop and delay by that amount. For example, you have 85 iterations, so each iteration would take approximately 12 ms.

If you don't mind blocking a thread, you can do this very easily with Threading.Thread.Sleep(12). If blocking is an issue, you'll likely want to use an external timer.

I found this link during a Google search. He explains how to set up a managed game loop in VB.Net.

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?737805-Vb-Net-Managed-Game-Loop

**UPDATE: Per OP's comment...**

To do this using timers, you'll want to manipulate the character object directly within the Timer event handler (Tick). You wouldn't use loops at all.

Set the Timer's Interval to the value discussed earlier - the number of ms corresponding to how long it takes to move 1 pixel. Then, in the Timer's Tick handler, set the character object's Location equal to a new Point with the new value. Also in the Tick handler, check your upper bound (15), then reverse the process until it hits the lower bound (100).

For example,

```
Private Sub tmrJump_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrJump.Tick
    If (intCounterY > 15 And blnGoingUp == True) Then 
        picSpaceRunner.Location = new Point(intCounterX, intCounterY - 1);
    End If

    ... Remaining Code Goes Here ...

End Sub
```

Comment: I am doing this as an assignment for school to I am forced to use timers to complete the lesson not delays. Is there any other way I could achieve the same effect.

Comment: Since it's for school, I don't want to simply give you the full code as an answer. However, my update should put you on the right path.

Comment: This causes the character to move up only one pixel and it does so instantly rather than gliding up in a jumping motion. Also the real issue of making him come back down wasn't tackled in your suggested code. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try breaking down the steps. There are a few key points to consider. Your pic is the only object that maintains position. When you set its location, that becomes your variable. In your code, you are using other variables to manage that. That's fine, but not necessary. You have to initialize your state - either in the form load or during button click. Once the state has been initialize, you can start the timer. The "remaining" code was for you to figure out. Inside the timer handler, you'll want to check the current location, determine a direction change, and set the new location.

Comment: I already have this in the code I just forgot to put it in.                                          Dim intCounterY As Integer = 100
    Dim intCounterX As Integer = 25

Comment: Ok. Inside your Tick handler, you'll need to set the Y variable to the new value. Otherwise, every interval, the value will be the same. For example, if you say "intCounterY - 1" in the Point constructor, you'll need to say "intCounterY = intCounterY - 1" after that.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the loop in the timer_tick. Increase or decrease the height by set interval instead and then check if the image had reached the maximum or minimum height.